Reason the light switch isn’t controlling the fan part?
I have a ceiling fan in my bedroom the light switch on the wall only controls the light part…To turn the fan part on and off I have to use the pull chain…Anybody know what could be the reason the light switch isn’t controlling the fan part?

Most likely you have house power in the ceiling.
The fan is directly connected to the power, but the light uses a switch loop.
The black house wire has one wire to the switch(should be white) and the fan connected to it.
The light power is connected to the black switch hot from the switch.  Some people do not want the fan on each time they want light, or the light on with the fan.
Can have the fan controlled by a wall switch also, but some rewiring will need to be done, plus drywall, painting.  A good job to do just before repainting of the room.

Is it possible to connect it to the switch instead of using an entire new switch?

@RenellWilliams  Possible, but would need to know if the fan can be wired that way.  You would need to drop the fan, since the connections will be above in the ceiling box.  You turn off the breaker first and make sure there is no power.  People(me) do turn off the wrong breaker sometimes.  Take pictures before undoing any wires.

@RenellWilliams  At least with the pull cord, you should not lose the choice of fan and/or light being on.
